# Switching channels failed error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:

Tags: flutter, dart

```
witching channels failed
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/6_infrastructure.md
dev/docs/dashing_postprocess.dart
dev/tools/dartdoc.dart
dev/tools/java_and_objc_doc.dart
dev/tools/test/dartdoc_test.dart
examples/api/lib/material/scaffold/scaffold_state.show_snack_bar.0.dart
packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/math.dart
packages/flutter/lib/src/services/dom.dart
packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart
packages/flutter/test/foundation/leak_tracking.dart
packages/flutter/test/foundation/leak_tracking_test.dart
packages/flutter/test/painting/widget_span_test.dart
packages/flutter/test/rendering/mock_canvas.dart
packages/flutter/test/rendering/mock_canvas_test.dart
packages/flutter/test/rendering/recording_canvas.dart
packages/flutter/test/widgets/fast_reassemble_test.dart
packages/flutter/test/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures_test.dart
packages/flutter_test/lib/src/all_elements.dart
packages/flutter_test/lib/src/buffer_matcher.dart
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_app_link_settings.dart
packages/flutter_tools/test/integration.shard/android_gradle_print_app_link_domains_test.dart
packages/flutter_tools/test/integration.shard/android_gradle_print_application_id_test.dart
packages/flutter_tools/test/integration.shard/single_widget_reload_test.dart
packages/flutter_tools/test/integration.shard/test_data/single_widget_reload_project.dart
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting.
```

hello guys, I am a new `dart` `flutter` user, and just now I upgraded my flutter version to the latest version. but recently I did something, where I accidentally moved my channel to the beta channel, and when I wanted to return to the stable channel I experienced this problem, I don't know what to do, and have looked for various platforms to solve this problem but can't find it, please help